# Pass additional GET params with @Html.TextBox helper

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have page with text input, table and pager. Text input is used to set number of table rows per page.

View code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Read", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Rows per page: @Html.TextBox("cnt", ViewBag.cnt as int?)  
            <input type="submit" value="Refresh" />
        </p>
    }
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Code", "Index", new { Order = ViewBag.CodeSortParm, cnt = ViewBag.cnt })      
                </th>
                <th>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Description", "Index", new { Order = ViewBag.TextSortParm, cnt = ViewBag.cnt }) 
                </th>
            </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model) { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                 @item.Code             
            </td>
            <td>
                 @item.Text 
            </td>
        </tr>
    } 
</table>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, cnt = ViewBag.cnt, Order = ViewBag.CurrentSort }) )
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Order, int? page, int? cnt)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = Order;
            ViewBag.CodeSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Order) ? "Code_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.TextSortParm = Order == "Text" ? "Text_desc" : "Text";

            ViewBag.cnt = cnt;

            Tbl T = new Tbl();
            IQueryable<ErrCode> ErrCodes = T.GetErrCodes();

            switch (Order)
            {
                case "Code_desc":
                    ErrCodes = ErrCodes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Code);
                    break;
                case "Text":
                    ErrCodes = ErrCodes.OrderBy(x => x.Text);
                    break;
                case "Text_desc":
                    ErrCodes = ErrCodes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Text);
                    break;
                default:
                    ErrCodes = ErrCodes.OrderBy(x => x.Code);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = cnt ?? 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            var onePageOfProducts = ErrCodes.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            return View(onePageOfProducts);
        }
```

When I press button "Refresh" it pass to controller only Cnt value. But I'd like to pass Order value too.
I try this variant:
`@Html.TextBox("cnt", ViewBag.cnt as int?, new { Order = ViewBag.CurrentSort })`
and this:
`Html.BeginForm("Index", "Read", FormMethod.Get, new { Order = ViewBag.CurrentSort })`
but it doesn't work (doesn't pass Order param to Controller).
What is right way to pass Order param to Controller when submit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that gets posted is what it is inside the Form.
So, you can place a `@Html.Hidden("Order", ViewBag.CurrentSort)`. This will post the order value, but will not be visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `@Html.Hidden("Order", new { ViewBag.CurrentSort })` works properly.